# Does Service Principal (SPN) values has to be change while doing ADAL.Net to MSAL.Net migration?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, adal

We have a Web Application in .Net Core 6.0 that we have registered in Azure AD app registration in azure portal.
We have used ADAL.net library in our code for Authentication. Now, we are migrating authentication library Adal.net to Msal.Net.
We have used below endpoints URLs to generate tokens

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize)
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

When we migrate the application, we have to change the library references and related code in our application.
We want to confirm on the below points -

- **Do we need do any changes in app registration configuration in azure portal or any code level configuration changes in application related to MSAL.Net Library like in appsettings or startup.cs class?**
- **Do we need to do any change in service principal (SPN) values?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ASP.NET Core 6.0, you should use Microsoft.Identity.Web, which provides higher-level APIs on top of MSAL.NET. See the migration guide [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/web-apps#migrating-from-previous-versions--adding-authentication). You do not need to change any of your app registration when migrating, include the service principal values.